# uber and kennedy space center

Tags: disney, uber, orlando

I'll be staying at the [Grand Floridian Resort in Disneyworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney%27s_Grand_Floridian_Resort_%26_Spa) on an upcoming trip. Four days for Disneyworld, I figure, and then I want to spend one full day doing the [Kennedy Space Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center). My plan is to take an Uber from the hotel to Kennedy Space Center and then, when I'm done, take an Uber back.

The concern I have is that the Kennedy Space Center is kinda isolated. The closest hotel appears to be ~10mi away.

My question is...  how easy will it be to catch an Uber from the Kennedy Space Center? Due to it's remoteness I don't imagine Uber drivers would exactly be plentiful there. A driver driving in downtown Orlando probably wouldn't drive out to the Kennedy Space Center to pick me up because they could get riders without having to drive a great distance. An Uber driver presumably only gets paid when they have a rider in the car so if they have to drive 30m just to get a rider that's 30m that they're not getting paid.

https://www.uber.com/fare-estimate/ suggests that it'd cost me $112.77 with an UberX but that doesn't tell me if it's even reasonable to expect Uber drivers to make that trek or how long I'd likely need to wait for an UberX to pick me up.

Is it realistic to think that an Uber might pick me up from the Kennedy Space Center or should I just plan on getting a rental vehicle?

Comment: Uber says the wait time right now is 5-15 min. (the 5 min one got picked up while I was typing.) They (x3) appear to be hanging out at a nearby parking lot which is Uber drivers' m.o. near tourist attractions in my experience. You could always schedule one in advance if you're nervous about it.

Comment: Why don't you just rent a car? It's only about an hour drive each way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not everyone can drive

Comment: @Mark Not everyone can drive, sure, but the OP has at least contemplated renting a car. I've actually been there and I wouldn't even think of trying to Uber it if renting a car was on the table.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I hate driving and I'm willing to pay a premium not to do it. Like if a rental would cost me $100 and an Uber would cost me $200 I'd do the Uber. But if the Uber was gonna cost me $1,000 whilst the rental was still costing me $100...  at that point I'd probably just swallow my discontent and do the rental.

Comment: @neubert Yeah, that's about how the difference is. With rental cars starting from $10 a day and uber at ... $112 ... But remember you have to go both ways.

Comment: I also see a number of tour bus services which provide shuttle service to KSC from Orlando, around $60/person return. If you aren't renting a car, this is probably your next cheapest option. But they tend to leave KSC pretty early in the evening, so you may have to cut your day short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plan and expectation is perfectly sound.  Both the entire Walt Disney World Resort and the Kennedy Space Center Visitor complex are UberX areas.  Walt Disney World is also an UberPool area if you're interested in sharing on the way out.

Uber does not inform the driver of your destination until they accept the ride and possibly only when they reach the pickup point so as long as Uber accepts the ride, you really don't need to worry about the driver.  I've spoken to many drivers and find they prefer long rides since they pay better over time.

Plan for ~$100 each way.  I've actually priced similar trips and they came in $85-$115.  Keep in mind, if you request a Pool, you pay the Pool fare even if no one else is picked up.  I got a $30 ride from Long Beach to Burbank that way once.

It will almost certainly be cheaper to rent a car for the day which you can do on property and very close by.  Alamo has a location right at the Car Care Center.  I think they have an on-request resort shuttle or you can just ask Bell Services at the Grand for the best way to get there.